# WIX How to include the equal signs and ampersand in the string table to avoid LGHT0104 error

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have a launch condition error string in String_en-US.wxl:

```
<WixLocalization Culture="en-us" Codepage="1252" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/localization">
    <String Id="ERR_REQUIRED_APP_ABSENT">This product requires XXX to be on the system. Please download it from "https://knowledge.xxx.com/knowledge/llisapi.dll?func=ll&objId=59284919&objAction=browse&sort=name&viewType=1", install it and try again.</String>
</WixLocalization>
```

It seems having the ampersand signs (&) and the equal signs (=) cause the light error:

```
Strings_en-US.wxl(0,0): error LGHT0104: Not a valid localization file; detail: '=' is an unexpected token. The expected token is ';'. Line 36, position 172.
```

I even tried to escape them using &#61; which is equivalent to the equal sign but it complaint about the ampersand. "How can I avoid the error?

Comment: [Does this work?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1091953/129130). Replace **`&`** with **`&amp;`**?

Comment: **`1)`** **CDATA**: *`<String Id="TEST1"><![CDATA[https://www.hi.com/one&two&three&v=1]]></String>`* and **`2)`** using **XML Escape Characters**:
  *`<String Id="TEST2">https://www.hi.com/one&amp;two&amp;three&amp;v=1</String>`*

Comment: The above compiled for me in Visual Studio, I didn't test via command line. Try removing the last `=` character for debugging. Then use escape characters like for the `&` if you need to.

Comment: @Stein, Thank you. (1) Using CDATA works! (2) Using the escape characters for the equal sign (&#61;) didn't work. Would you put your comment in the answer? I will choose it as an answer.

Comment: Not sure the equal sign needs to be escaped? I think it is your **`"`** characters that are problematic. Do you need the URL in quotes? Maybe try using single quotes: **`'`**? 'URLHERE'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***CDATA***: A [CDATA section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA) is "*...a section of element content that is marked for the parser to interpret as only character data, not markup.*"

In this case, something like this:

```
<String Id="TEST1"><![CDATA[https://www.hi.com/one&two&three&v=1]]></String>
```

---

[***XML Escape Characters***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1091953/129130): XML escape characters are normally used for encoding special characters in XML documents. The escape character for **`&`** is & **`&amp;`** ([more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1091953/129130)) - CDATA is an alternative approach.

---

***Links:***

- [What characters do I need to escape in XML documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/what-characters-do-i-need-to-escape-in-xml-documents/1091953#1091953)
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA